# $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$ are independent exponential random variables with rates 1, 2, 3, and 4, respectively.

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

What is $P(X_1<X_2<X_3<X_4|X_2<X_4)$? I assume I need to use the formula for conditional probability so $$P(X_1<X_2<X_3<X_4|X_2<X_4)=\frac{P(X_1<X_2<X_3<X_4,X_2<X_4)}{P(X_2<X_4)}$$

The bottom of this is easy to find: $P(X_2 < X_4)= \frac{2}{2+4}=\frac13$. But I'm not sure how to do the top. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the numerator, note that if $A=X_1<X_2<X_3<X_4$ and $B=X_2<X_4$, then 
$$P(B|A)=1 \rightarrow P(A,B)=P(A)P(B|A)=P(A)$$
so the numerator simplifies to $P(X_1<X_2<X_3<X_4)$. You can follow the same method as you used for the denominator to work out the numerator.

Comment: I also have a question that is related to this one if you don't mind. I need to find $P(X_1 < 3X_2 + X_3 + 5X_4)$ which I know is equal to $1 - P(X_1 \geq 3X_2 + X_3 + 5X_4)=1-P(X_1\geq 3X_2)P(X_1\geq X_3)P(X_1\geq 5X_4))$ but I'm not sure how to find each of those individual probabilities other than $P(X_1 \geq X_3)$

Comment: If $X$ is exponential, then consider the variable transformation $Y=3X$. You will find that $Y$ is exponential. I think you can take it from there.